# \newtheorem{def} throws an error

Tags: theorems, amsthm

The following is a piece of the code I am working on. It says that there is an error with \newtheorem{def} but I really don't understand why. Thank you very much for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set the margins to 1in on all sides
\usepackage{graphicx}              % to include figures
\usepackage{amsmath}               % great math stuff
\usepackage{amsfonts}              % for blackboard bold, etc
\usepackage{amsthm}                % better theorem environments
\usepackage{esint}          


\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}

\newtheorem{def}[thm]{Definition}
```

It throws an error even if I do not include "\begin{def}, \end{def}" in my code.

Comment: maybe this has to do with the fact that `\def` is a TeX primitive and `\begin{def}` implies the definition of corresponding `\def` and `\enddef` macros, with an obvious conflict

Comment: the solution here is just to use a different shortcut such as `defn` or `Def`

Comment: that works, thanks a lot for your help! :) what a noobish question I asked ahahah

Comment: it's not noobish, it's never so obvious what happens with macro definitions without digging in the internals of LaTeX a bit...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message you're getting should tell you all you need to know:

> LaTeX Error: Command \def already defined.

What's going on? You're trying to set up a new (theorem-like) environment called `def`. In practice, this means that LaTeX tries to set up an instruction called `\def` to deal with the instruction `\begin{def}`. (LateX also sets up a macro `\enddef`.) Can you spot the problem?

Comment: I do! thank you too for the prompt reply, I really appreciate!

Comment: @user01123581321345589144... - the fix is simple, as Bordaigorl has pointed out, is simple: call the environment `defn`, or `definition`, or even `Def` (though the latter is inviting lots of confusion, I suspect).

Comment: @user01123581321345589144... I add a recommendation: when you see a message such as `Command \foo already defined`, take it seriously and don't try overriding the definition unless you know precisely what you're doing. Redefining `\def`, for instance, would be disastrous; if you want to have fun, add `\let\def\relax` just before `\newtheorem{def}{Definition}` and see what happens. `;-)` *That* error message isn't issued, but… `:-D`